# Salty Vagrant Master hostname: salt not found

Tags: vagrant, provisioning, salt-stack

I am trying to load my vagrant box with salt, asking it to install Apache.
I am using [salty-vagrant](https://github.com/saltstack/salty-vagrant#configuration) in masterless mode.

The vagrant box gets loaded, but it gets stuck in the console with the following message:

```
[default] Running provisioner: salt...
Checking if salt-minion is installed
salt-minion found
Checking if salt-call is installed
salt-call found
Salt did not need installing or configuring.
Calling state.highstate... (this may take a while)
```

When I check the vagrant salt log, the following is found:

```
[salt.utils       ][ERROR   ] This master address: 'salt' was previously resolvable but now fails to resolve! The previously resolved ip addr will continue to be used

[salt.minion      ][WARNING ] Master hostname: salt not found. Retrying in 30 seconds
```

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you are passing a minion config with the following option set:

```
file_client: local
```

Read all the steps in the Masterless Quick Start: https://github.com/saltstack/salty-vagrant#masterless-quick-start